# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RedirectBinding - AuthnRequest without ds:Signature element

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm trying to implement ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library to send AuthnRequest to IdP with redirect binding. The IdP requires ds:Signature element to be presented in AuthnRequest, but when I set saml2Configuration.SignAuthnRequest to `true` as recommended [here](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/issues/23), the Signature element is still not there. It works with post binding, but I would like to use redirect binding.

In the code I see there is `XmlDocument = XmlDocument.SignDocument(...)` in [Saml2PostBinding.BindInternal()](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Bindings/Saml2PostBinding.cs) but it is not in [Saml2RedirectBinding.BindInternal()](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Bindings/Saml2RedirectBinding.cs)

Is there any reason why it is not in redirect binding as well? Am I somehow able to get Signature element there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a AuthnRequest is signed using a PostBinding the signature is added to the XML.

But if you do a RedirectBinding the signature and sign method is added as URL paramenters along side the SAMLRequest parameter, like this example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is that standardized way how AuthnRequest is signed in redirect binding? In specification from IdP the Signature element should be presented in the request, so I would prefer to have it there instead of signing query string.

Comment: As of my knowledge the standard is as I described in the answer.